# VB.Net - Manage errors label

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, label

I'm working on visual studio 2015 and I'm working on a classic subscribing form.

I want to generate error labels when the user type wrong password, the wrong pseudo, etc. But I can work on it myself.

But when I write those error labels and set their visible at false in "Dev mode", I have to juxtapose those labels if I want my labels at the same place, and it's not what I want when I have many errors to manage on one textBox for example.

Is there a solution to gererate those labels, without write them before playing with hide() or show() ?

Here is the screenshot in order to illustrate my problem.

[image]

It's not really a problem itself, but It's not practical when I'm develop many errors.

Sorry for my english, I hope you understood my problem, I can give you more details =)

Have a nice day full of code !

Comment: You might want to look at the ErrorProvider and see if it is close enough to what you want

Comment: Yeahhhhhh I will check de doc, thank you :)

Comment: You can create your own control? I've done this before and works just fine. I inherited the Textbox control and extended it.

Answer (score 0):

Here the button code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "Password" Then
        Label2.Text = "Your answer is wrong"
    End If
End Sub
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: check this link